# How to preselect an option in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Hi I want to know how to preselect to option. I think I can do it with javascript since I manage to get the countrycode but not the dropdown to get set appropriately:

[image]

In this case I want also the dropdodown to get populated to "England" which has the value GB. How can I do it? My JSP is:

```
<input type="text" class="inp_sel" size="2"
         name="<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_LANDKOD%>"
         id="<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_LANDKOD%>"
         value="<%if (ansokanInfo.getUppfinnareList().contains(editPerson)|| ansokanInfo.getSokandeList().contains(editPerson)){ out.write(editPerson.getLandKod());}%>"         
         onkeyup="setListbox(event, this, '<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_LAND%>')";
         onmousedown="setListboxEmpty(this)";>                                                 
         <SELECT name="<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_LAND%>" 
          id="<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_LAND%>"
          class="inp_sel" onChange="setSearchbox(this, '<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_LANDKOD%>')">
          <% for(LandKod land: pc.getLander()) { %> 
          <OPTION value="<%=land.getLandKod()%>"
          <% if (land.getLandKod().equalsIgnoreCase("SE")) {
          out.println("SELECTED");
          } %>
```

And my javascript is

```
function setListbox(e, obj, id) {

     //               sokLandkod input
     //               sokLand select

     if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 8) { return; }
     if (obj.value.length < 2) { return; }

     var landList = document.getElementById(id);
     var searchKod = obj.value;
     var len = searchKod.length;
     obj.value = "";

     for (var i = 0; i < landList.options.length; i++) {

                       sListValue = landList.options[i].value;
                       var matchIx = sListValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchKod.toUpperCase());

     if (matchIx == 0) {
                       landList.selectedIndex = i;
                       obj.value = landList.options[i].value;
                       break;
     }
     }
}


function setSearchbox(obj, id) {

     var iny = 'sokLandkod'
     var searchKod = obj.value;
     document.getElementById(id).value = searchKod;
}

          ><%=land.getLandNamn() %>
          </OPTION>
          <% } %>
          </SELECT>
```

Can you advice me how to set the option?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If England's value is **"GB"**... you should change the following snippet to select **"GB"** and not **"SE"** (Is that the value of Sverige?):

```
<% if (land.getLandKod().equalsIgnoreCase("SE")) { 
  out.println("SELECTED"); 
} %>
```

Unless, I misunderstood your data... It will look like this then.

```
<% if (land.getLandKod().equalsIgnoreCase("GB")) { 
  out.println("SELECTED"); 
} %>
```

Comment: I could fix it doing something similar. Thank you for the answer.